# Design time data

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone, design-time-data

Using *design-time data* for my *Windows Phone Apps* which works fine for **string**, **int** etc. (e.g. here: Person name, Person age) but when I like to do that for "nested object" (e.g. here: Company/Employer) I have no idea how to do this in the design-time-data-XAML file.

**Company:**

```
public class Company
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

**Person:**

```
public class Person
{
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Company Employer { get; set; }
}
```

**PersonViewModel.cs:**

"Normal" ViewModel which implements INotifyPropertyChanged and has properties for all data I want to display.

**PersonViewModelSampleData.xaml:**

```
<local:PersonViewModel 
    xmlns="http:schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http:schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Hfr.BlaBla.ViewModels"

    Name="Harald-René Flasch"
    Age="36">
</local:PersonViewModel>
```

**Person Page XAML:**

```
<TextBlock
    Text="{Binding Path=Employer.Name}"
    Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"
    TextWrapping="Wrap" ... />
```

So, **Path=Employer.Name** works fine at run-time but I have no idea how to provide that data for design-time support. Any suggestions?

Comment: i think you can only do that by Assigning FallBackValue

Comment: The easiest way to generate design time data is to use Blend. http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/07/12/design-time-data-for-windows-phone.aspx and a follow up article: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/07/23/disable-design-time-data.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your sample data : it would be an instance of `Person` OR an instance of `PersonViewModel` (but in that case the viewModel should have a property of type `Company` or `Person` or both).

If your sample data is an instance of Person :

```
<local:Person
    xmlns="http:schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http:schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Hfr.BlaBla.MyModelsNamespace"

    Name="Harald-René Flasch"
    Age="36">
     <local:Person.Employer>
             <local:Company Name="MyCompany"/>
     </local:Person.Employer>
</local:Person>
```

Be carefull of namespaces : here the "local" xmlns refers to the model namespace (not the viewModel).

**EDIT :**
If your sample data is the viewModel, assuming that your ViewModel as a property `Employer` with a setter (not only a getter), of type `Company`  :

```
<local:PersonViewModel 
    xmlns="http:schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http:schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Hfr.BlaBla.ViewModels"
    xmlns:myModel="clr-namespace:Hfr.BlaBla.MyModelsNamespace"
    Name="Harald-René Flasch"
    Age="36">
    <local:PersonViewModel.Employer>
            <myModel:Company Name="MyCompany"/>
    </local:PersonViewModel.Employer>
</local:PersonViewModel>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, using MVVM pattern and the design-time-data is the ViewModel of course (PersonViewModelSampleData.xaml). Didn't add the PersonViewModel C# code here since it is nothing special (implements all properties which I want to display and it implements INotifyPropertyChanged). {Binding Path=Employer.Name} works fine for runtime.

Comment: YES, you did it! Forgot to add the namespace for the "domain model" (also forgot a default ctor for the Company domain item which is necessary for the Designer). Thanks a lot!